# Reading Data from Multiple txt Files in Java

Tags: java, file, input

I'm a beginner taking Intro to Computer Science and I'm working with java. I get the following error in this program when trying to read from multiple txt files in the getLetterGrade method:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Exam
{
    private int grade;
    private float examAvg;
    private String name;
    private File exam1Data;
    private File exam2Data;
    private File namesData;
    private Scanner inFileExam1;
    private Scanner inFileExam2;
    private Scanner inFileName;

    //constructor
    public Exam() throws IOException
    {
        exam1Data = new File("exam1.txt");
        exam2Data = new File("exam2.txt");
        namesData = new File("names.txt");
        inFileExam1 = new Scanner(exam1Data);
        inFileExam2 = new Scanner(exam2Data);
        inFileName = new Scanner(namesData);
    }

public float getExam1Avg()
{
examAvg = 0;

while (inFileExam1.hasNext()) {
grade = inFileExam1.nextInt();
examAvg += grade;
}
inFileExam1.close();
examAvg = (float)(examAvg / 25.0);
return examAvg;
}

public float getExam2Avg()
{
examAvg = 0;

while (inFileExam2.hasNext()) {
grade = inFileExam2.nextInt();
examAvg += grade;
}
inFileExam2.close();
examAvg = (float)(examAvg / 25.0);
return examAvg;
}

    //method that finds the letter grade given a student name and
    //the exam number
    public char getLetterGrade(String inputName, int examNum)
    {
        char letter;
        int count = 1;

        //inputName = inputName.toLowerCase();

        do {
            if (inFileName.hasNext()){
                name = inFileName.nextLine();
            }
            count++;
        } while (inFileName.hasNext() && !name.equalsIgnoreCase(inputName));

        inFileName.close();

        if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(inputName)) {
            return 'x';
        }

        if (examNum == 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= count && inFileExam1.hasNextInt(); i++) {
                grade = inFileExam1.nextInt();
            }
            inFileExam1.close();
        }
        else if (examNum == 2) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= count && inFileExam2.hasNextInt(); i++) {
                grade = inFileExam2.nextInt();
            }
            inFileExam2.close();
        }
        else {
            return 'x';
        }

        if (grade >= 90) {
            letter = 'A';
        }
        else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80) {
            letter = 'B';
        }
        else if (grade < 80 && grade >= 70) {
            letter = 'C';
        }
        else if (grade < 70 && grade >= 60) {
            letter = 'D';
        }
        else {
            letter = 'F';
        }

        return letter;
    }
}
```

The error occurs at the following line:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count && inFileExam1.hasNextInt(); i++) {
```

Please help!!

Here is the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ExamAverages
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
Exam exam = new Exam();
System.out.println(exam.getExam1Avg());
System.out.println(exam.getExam2Avg());
System.out.println(exam.getLetterGrade("name", 1));
}
```

Comment: What is the data in the two `inFileExam*` files?

Comment: exam1.txt data:


67
56
90
77
45
87
23
12
87
89
96
44
55
66
22
88
99
77
59
100
2
47
60
8
81

exam2.txt data:


76
34
11
77
44
33
77
88
97
65
79
71
72
45
54
68
32
83
49
88
79
81
93
58
75


All numbers are written on separate lines btw.. don't know if that matters.

Comment: Dude, you are just making your post more complicated and unreadable.. stick to the main problem

Comment: Can you also explain how you code is supposed to work with all these files

Answer (score 0):

you are closing your scanner

```
inFileName.close();
```

and then trying to use it again without opening as like:

```
inFileName = new Scanner(..);
```

**EDIT1**
It does not fail for me, but maybe i have missed some stuff (I still don't know how exactly you are willing to read these files, how they relate to each other)

```
public char getLetterGrade(String inputName, int examNum) {
    char letter;
    int count = 0;

    do {
        if (inFileName.hasNext()) {
            name = inFileName.nextLine();
        }
        count++;
    } while (inFileName.hasNext() && !name.equalsIgnoreCase(inputName));

    if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(inputName)) {
        return 'x';
    }

    if (examNum == 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count && inFileExam1.hasNextInt(); i++) {
            grade = inFileExam1.nextInt();
        }
        inFileExam1.close();
    } else if (examNum == 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count && inFileExam2.hasNextInt(); i++) {
            grade = inFileExam2.nextInt();
        }
        inFileExam2.close();
    } else {
        return 'x';
    }

    if (grade >= 90) {
        letter = 'A';
    } else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80) {
        letter = 'B';
    } else if (grade < 80 && grade >= 70) {
        letter = 'C';
    } else if (grade < 70 && grade >= 60) {
        letter = 'D';
    } else {
        letter = 'F';
    }

    return letter;
}
```

Comment: that's not the Scanner that has the problem. It's a problem with the inFileExam1 Scanner.

Comment: supply all the code then, so we will see it. Otherwise this exception is just because of multiple Scanner instances being instantiated without closing them

Comment: I have other methods as well, I'll add them too

Comment: in your code if you just delete/comment out "inFileName.close();" everything will work, since we are not really sure what you have in the files stored, then we cannot debug it(I cannot), but as long as I tried now reading files, getting output, it works, just comment/delete this line

Comment: hmm.. I deleted it, but it's still not working. I have to leave now. I'll check back here when I get home. Thanks all for your help so far, I appreciate it and hope you will continue to help me!!

Comment: edited my post. now it takes the name as input, counts the line number where name is written, then extracts the *points from the file 1 or 2 (same line as name) and changes pints to letter.. As i mentioned in the post, i am not sure if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're resetting `grade` every time you read a line, and you aren't doing anything with it, so that part of the code is useless.

But to answer your question:

According to the API, `Scanner` only returns an `IllegalStateException` after the object is closed using `Scanner.close()` or is somehow closed by the system.

Try moving your `Scanner` declaration for `inFileExam1` next to where you are using it, like this:

```
if (examNum == 1) {
        inFileExam1 = new Scanner(exam1Data); // Add this
        for (int i = 1; i <= count && inFileExam1.hasNextInt(); i++) {
            grade = inFileExam1.nextInt();
        }
        inFileExam1.close();
    }
    else if (examNum == 2) {
        inFileExam2 = new Scanner(exam2Data); // And this
        for (int i = 1; i <= count && inFileExam2.hasNextInt(); i++) {
            grade = inFileExam2.nextInt();
        }
        inFileExam2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code exactly as you did, but now I get the following run-time error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown ... :(

Comment: make the method throw an `IOException` like this: `getLetterGrade(...) throws IOException {`

Comment: I commented out the inFileExam1 and inFileExam2 assignments in the constructor, and I also added the "throws IOException" for the getLetterGrade method... but now I get a different error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

... it says the error first occurs at the line:
    while (inFileExam1.hasNext()){

Comment: did you mean `while(inFileName.hasNext() {`? Otherwise I don't see that line in the code. Is there another class that is running this? If so please edit the question with that code added.

Comment: I just changed it to while (inFileName.hasNextInt(){ but I get same error.. I updated the original post with the main class and my entire code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the code that has your main method, but I'm going to make an educated guess that you construct a new `Exam` object in it, and call `getLetterGrade` more than once. Since you open your `Scanners` in the constructor, and close them after reading, the *second* time you call `getLetterGrade` you will see an `IllegalStateException`.

If this psychic reading is inaccurate, can you please update your post with the contents of `main(String[] args)`?

*EDIT:* After your latest edit I see that you call the `getExam1Avg` method before calling `getLetterGrade`. Since `getExam1Avg` calls `close` on your `Scanner` you get an IllegalStateException when calling the other method. You need to either instantiate a new scanner for each method call or otherwise reset the scanners after each method is complete.

Comment: I don't know how to edit the main post... but i'm just making an Exam object and using a System.out.println(getLetterGrade("name", 1));

Comment: @user1082587 at the bottom of your question, there is an `edit` button on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `getAverageExam1Avg` and the other one. Instead of closing your `Scanner`s in  the `getLetterGrade` method, you should keep them open and add a `close` method like this:

```
public void close() {
    inFileName.close();
    inFileExam1.close();
    inFileExam2.close();
}
```

Make sure to add the proper exceptions into that code.

The reason it is failing now is because you haven't opened the Scanners. Un-comment the instantiations in the constructor.

If this doesn't work, I have no idea what will.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I took away the constructor and the File and Scanner field declarations. Instead I created File and Scanner objects for each method. No more run-time error. :) For those wondering what I'm trying to do: I'm taking a string input (student's name) from the user and matching it with the same string in the names.txt file while counting how many lines down the string is located. Then I find the corresponding exam grade (integer) from either exam1.txt or exam2.txt which should be located the same line number.

Comment: It's still not working perfectly as I'm not getting the correct results, but I think I should be able to handle it from here. If I have more trouble, I'll let you guys know. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I just initialized the count variable to 0 instead of 1 as Boris did. It works fine now.

Comment: So was this the correct answer? Or are you just commenting on this? You should accept the answer that fixed the problem, but if none of them did, just leave it.